# Go module as dependency manager for go1.10?

Tags: go

I am starting to work with GO, and I have no experience with GO.
I would like to know if it is possible to use Go modules in GO 1.10.
Thank you guys.

Comment: Why not upgrade to go 1.15?

Comment: Use Go 1.15. Never (!!) use outdated, old, unsupported stuff like 1.10.

Comment: I understand that I better migrate to go1.15. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Given that module support was added in Go 1.11, the answer is "No".

Comment: Thank, So, I think I'm going to have to migrate to the Go1.11 version

Comment: @IgorLeonardoPereiradaSilva No, you sould migrate to go 15. There is no reason to migrate to an old, unsupported version.